# Magento Tablerates ignores the last part of the postal codes 1793"EB" the "EB" part

Tags: shipping-methods

Is there a way to ignore the last part of the postal code the "EB" part? So that it only looks at the first part the "1790" part.

Now when I fill in 1793 only, it works. But when I fill in 1793EB, it doesn't work and it goes back to the default price for that land.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates` and replace `$request->setDestPostcode($this->getPostcode());` with `$request->setDestPostcode((int)$this->getPostcode());`

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick awnser! I am fairly new to magenoto. So in which file do I need to edit this?

Comment: don't edit the core. You need to properly rewrite it.  See this on how you can rewrite a model: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/. Also the class name determines the file. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address is in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this! I will let you know if it will work!!

Comment: I have changed "$request->setDestPostcode($this->getPostcode());" with "$request->setDestPostcode((int)$this->getPostcode());" but it still shows the default price, i have flushed the cache.

Comment: do you have any idea of why this isn't working?

Comment: I have no other ideas.